# Combine JPG's into one PDF with PHP

Tags: php, pdf, imagemagick, jpeg, centos7

I'm trying to take a series of JPG's and combine them into one PDF file with each JPG being it's own page.  I'm guessing ImageMagick is the best way to do this, however I can't seem to figure out how to combine the files.  I see the combineImages method here :

http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.combineimages.php

But cannot find any examples.  I'm new to imagemagick so I'm still trying to figure out the syntax.

Can ImageMagick do what I'm asking?  And if so can someone write up a quick example?

Thanks!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In `PHP` you can use:

```
$images = array("file1.jpg", "file2.jpg");

$pdf = new Imagick($images);
$pdf->setImageFormat('pdf');
$pdf->writeImages('combined.pdf', true);
```

The `true` parameter on `writeImages` is important because it will make the method write a sequence of images, not only one.

---

You also can do this from command line:

```
convert file1.jpg file2.jpg output.pdf
```

Comment: Hi, i have used the above code. Pdf conversion is working fine. But the image color format changed (CMYK to RGB).  I need to the pdf same color format of source file ( CMYK).

Comment: To set the colorspace of the output file use `$pdf->setImageColorspace (imagick::COLORSPACE_CMYK);`. In case you want the exact same space as input you can try something like this `$page = new Imagick("colorsCMYK.jpg");
$pdf->setImageColorspace ( $page->getImageColorspace() );`

Comment: That worked well for me, but worth pointing out that pdf writing is disabled by default for security reasons. I found this helpful: https://andy-carter.com/blog/how-to-fix-imagickexception-not-authorized

Comment: What ? Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'not authorized `combined.pdf' @ error/constitute.c/WriteImage/1

Comment: this looks like the rights problem. https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/blob/f548a590c00313db021a687323ee6eb5f30d1e62/MagickCore/constitute.c#L416