# Combine JPG's on the fly into one PDF with PHP

Tags: php, pdf, jpeg, imagick

i see code [Combine JPG's into one PDF with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25680490/combine-jpgs-into-one-pdf-with-php) but i need combine jpg on the fly to one pdf possible can do it ?

```
$totalFile = count($resultJ);
foreach ($resultJ as $key) {
    $runPage = substr("000" . $i, -3);
    $name = "pages-$runPage.jpg";
    $images[$cThumb->writeToImageFile($key->{path} . $key->{uid})]; // on fly
    $i++;
}

//$images = array("file1.jpg", "file2.jpg");
//
$pdf = new Imagick($images);
$pdf->setImageFormat('pdf');
$pdf->writeImages('combined.pdf', true);
```

Comment: What is the difference between your question and the linked one?

Comment: use jpg on  the fly with water make, not have real file